# POST request sent on a second or a third click of the input button, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios

So everything in my code works pretty much as intended only the post request is sent on a second or maybe even on a third click on the button... I am guessing that it has something to to with the way I am updating redux state, but my brain froze, can someone please point out to me where is my mistake?

Cheers!

```
class AddressScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    usersNickOrName: "",
    usersAddress: "",
    usersPhoneNumber: ""
  };

  onPressHandler = () => {
    this.props.deliveryInfo(
      this.state.usersNickOrName,
      this.state.usersAddress,
      this.state.usersPhoneNumber
    );

    let uid = this.props.uid;

    axios.post(
      `.../users/${uid}/info.json`,
      {
        nameOrNick: this.props.name,
        address: this.props.address,
        phoneNum: this.props.phoneNum
      }
    );
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <AnimatedForm delay={100} distance={10}>
          <AnimatedInput
           onChangeText={text => {
              this.setState({ usersNickOrName: text });
            }}
          />
          <AnimatedInput
            onChangeText={text => {
              this.setState({ usersAddress: text });
            }}
          />
          <AnimatedInput
            onChangeText={text => {
              this.setState({ usersPhoneNumber: text });
            }}
          />

          <Animated.View style={styles.buttonView}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={this.onPressHandler}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>Dodaj Info</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Animated.View>
        </AnimatedForm>
      </View>
    );
  }
}



const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    name: state.usersNickOrName,
    address: state.usersAddress,
    phoneNum: state.usersPhoneNumber,
    uid: state.userUid
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    deliveryInfo: (usersName, usersAddress, phoneNum) =>
      dispatch(deliveryInfo(usersName, usersAddress, phoneNum))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AddressScreen);
```

EDIT:

What I did is, I have put my redux update state in componentWillUpdate and removed it from onPressHandler. Now it works almost like intended, for example if I enter London Str. 36 it will POST request London Str. 3, it wont send last letter or number to server... How come?

```
componentWillUpdate() {
    this.props.deliveryInfo(
      this.state.usersNickOrName,
      this.state.usersAddress,
      this.state.usersPhoneNumber
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried it with all forms of debugging/logging turned off? Sometimes the console statements or the debugger bring down the app's performance.

Comment: Hi Uzair, yes, I did try turning RN debugger also, but its the same just faster of course , I still need to click 2x on the button to send the post request.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I can see in your implementation, `the post request` will always be called by the button(`TouchableOpacity`). What you can do to prevent this, is to implement a functionality that will check if there is an ongoing `post request` before attempting to fire `a new post request`.

Comment: Hi, i actually want to send post request with every click, because after the post was sent, it pops the page and conditionally  that page will not appear if that post was sent. Problem is that i see in debuger that an action is dispatched, popped page but req was not sent, then when i try the second time, req is sent...